# Redux reducer not getting state argument

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am new to Redux and Saga. I have an app that is calling an api for data and the call is working. I'm getting back data. However, I can't figure out how to put that data into the state. The way I am trying does not work. When my Reducer gets called after this code executes, state is not provided.

```
 export function* downloadSeriesAsync(action) {
  try {
    let response = yield call(axios.get, '/content/series.json')
    yield put(downloadSeriesSuccess(response.data))
  }catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

This is my Saga function that calls the API.

```
 yield put(downloadSeriesSuccess(response.data))
```

the method downloadSeriesSuccess is an action creator that sends an action, FYI. I don't know if this is the right way to do this.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    console.log('Calling the with State', state);
  if (action.type === c.ADD_DOWNLOADED_SERIES) {
    let newState = { ...state };
    newState.series = [...newState.series, action.payload];
    return newState;
  }
  else {
    return state;
  }
}
```

I'm stuck on a problem. My state is always equals = [].

EDIT: I realized that my initial state is not an array, so I changed all the reducers to take an empty object instead. {}.  However, I noticed that after my middleware code executes, initial state seems to be changed back to an array.

```
export default (initialState={}) => {
  console.log('Initial State', initialState);
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const all = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, consoleLog)(createStore)(appReducer, initialState);
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);  
  return all;
}
```

I can't find any information as to why that is happening. This is also the point at which my state seems to turn empty.

Comment: What's the value of `c.ADD_DOWNLOADED_SERIES` / does it match the action type from `downloadSeriesSuccess`? Could you post the code for them? My guess would be that the the if statement isn't getting triggered, only the else clause, but it's hard to say without seeing those pieces of code.

Comment: Yes, it matches. The console.log above the 'if' statement shows that the state is = [] before executing the if statement.

Comment: As user suggested above, something inside your action creator might be acting up.  To rule out the action creator, try replacing `yield put(downloadSeriesSuccess(response.data))` with `yield put('YOUR_ACTION_CONSTANT_STRING', payload: response.data)`.  If this works, then you'll know your issue is inside the action creator function.